# Get the last date before selected date from ACCESS in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access DATABASE with date column in table, the dates are sorted but there can be missing dates. The problem is to get the latest date before the input date. For example I managed to solve this problem in excel sheet with just this `{=MAX(IF(A1:A10<=C1,A1:A10,0))}` formula, but I have a DataBase with large amount of data and need to call it from DB with formula.

I tried to write a code, but it doesn't work. I don't get why ?  Could anyone  help me with this problem ? thanks.

```
Public Function GetDateDB(TBL As String, COLMN As String, DT As String) As Variant

Dim DB As Database
Dim RS As Recordset
Dim DBfile

DBfile = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myDatabase.accdb"

Set DB = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(DBfile)
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT MAX(" & COLMN & ") as MaxDate FROM " & TBL & " WHERE MaxDate <= #" & Format(DT, "m\/d\/yyyy") & "# ", dbOpenDynaset)

If RS.RecordCount > 0 Then
    RS.MoveFirst
    GetDateDB = RS!MaxDate
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i consider, you only need to replace the `... WHERE MaxDate <= ...` by `... WHERE MaxDate < ...`.  (Just delete the equals-symbol)

When you search with <= you will in most cases get the input date.

Comment: Hi, Dorian,  In both cases it returns `"#VALUE!"`

Comment: Ok, then try to run the function in the immediate window. That will show you a better error message. Maybe you only need to reference "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library" (and delete the reference to "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library" or set it to a lower priority).

Comment: sorry, i didn't see you are the guy from yesterday's question, so you will already have the correct references... what error does the function throw when you run it in the immediate window?

Comment: Hmmm, i don't see a syntax error in your SQL-statement. Maybe your tablename or columnname have illegal characters like space or leading numbers etc. Try to use squared brackets. This could work: `"SELECT MAX([" & COLMN & "]) as MaxDate FROM [" & TBL & "] WHERE MaxDate <= #" & Format(DT, "m\/d\/yyyy")`

Comment: Sorry , I made some changes and it gave me another error. I'll write it under my question

Comment: your Sub won't work because it can't assign a value to itself. The `GetDateDB = RS!MaxDate` can't work. The `MsgBox GetDateDB` won't work as well. You can either use `MsgBox RS!MaxDate` or you undo your edits and write `?GetDateDb("CB_EXCHANGE", "RDATE", "07.07.2015")` into the immediate window.

Comment: OK, I did it. and it gave me an error 
`run-time error '3075' syntax error in date in query expression 'MaxDate < #07.07.2015'.`

Comment: sorry, the ending sharp (#) is missing and the date is not in the correct format. Do you have the `Format(DT, "m\/d\/yyyy")` in your instruction? Try to initialize DT as a Date `Public Function GetDateDB(TBL As String, COLMN As String, DT As Date) As Variant` so it should notice that it's a variable that can be formatted as "m\/d\/yyyy".

Comment: You will laugh if I say where the problem was: 
my system's format is dd/mm/yy , 
`?GetDateDb("CB_EXCHANGE", "RDATE", "07/07/2015"). `
Anyway, Thank you for your help. ))))

Comment: You're welcome. You should try different dates, because the format dd/mm/yy can easily be mixed up with m/d/yyyy. Check if the function returns the correct value.